# How to calculate a variable and send it as a header in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, header, hmac

I am trying to calculate a variable value in order to send that value as a header in JMETER, something like this:

```
Date timestamp = new Date();
String now = DateUtils.toIso8601Date(timestamp);
vars.put("timestamp", "hello");
```

I put this code in a beanshell preprocessor and then used the following syntax in a header manager hoping to send the timestamp as a header:

[image]

However the value of the variable is not being replaced in the header. Further down the line I want to be able to use code to calculate an HMAC signature and send it as a header. Is there any way to do this in jmeter? use a script to calculate a header value and then send it? I've done this in postman with the pre-req scripts but I don't see a similar mechanism in jmeter.
Thanks

Comment: `vars.put("timestamp", "hello");` --> you set a variable with value "hello"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This `DateUtils.toIso8601Date` function is not something I'm aware of, it's neither present in [Java SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html) nor in libraries which come with JMeter. If you're using a custom library which provides this function you will need to:

   - copy it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
   - restart JMeter to pick it up
   - add an [import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) statement to load it
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) especially when it comes to "heavy" tasks like cryptographic operations so consider migrating. More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

Comment: It was the JSR223...thanks!